# Read any file in Android not working for docx

Tags: android

I am making an app that should be able to receive and read any file.  Here is the code so far.

```
 documentViewHolder.preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    File document = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/heyJudeDocuments/" + getItem(position).attachment_id);  // -> filename = maven.pdf
                    Uri path = Uri.fromFile(document);
                    Intent docIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    docIntent.setDataAndType(path, getItem(position).mime);
                    docIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                    try {
                        activity.startActivity(docIntent);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "No Application available to view Document", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });
```

This is working perfectly for pdf and for ICS files but for docx I am getting an unexpected result.  The app opens up word but then i get an error "Can't open file".  If I email myself the same document and open it from gmail it works fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: `making an app that should be able to receive and read any file`. To receive any file is very simple. But to read -and handle- all file types is quite impossible. You are not even trying to read one in the posted code. Please rephrase.

Comment: `// -> filename = maven.pdf` ?? Please put the .docx filename in your code.

Comment: `i get an error "Can't open file".` From which app? Is it really called 'word' ?

Comment: `getItem(position).mime`, We cannot see what you put in there. Please show reproducable code.

Comment: `The app opens up word ` Is it? Cannot the user choose wich app to use?

Comment: You could install an Intent catcher app to see how GMail uses an Intent.